# c# wpf need to multiselect grid cells with mouse (NOT DataGrid control)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, grid

I have a standard Grid in my WPF form with "n" rows and "n" columns.

I wish to select and highlight the background of a selection of cells in one row by using the mouse left down and "dragging" the "highlight" across to the cells - each cell's background is highlighted for each one that the mouse-left-down moves over.

I currently have code working that will select one cell - using the mouse left down event that I have attached to the textblock assigned to the cell (row/column).

Does anyone have any idea how I can do the multiple select?

I have seen this working on the telerik grid but I am not in the position to use the Telerik controls.

(Googling brings up loads of Datagrid answers that do not answer the problem)

Will post code if I need to.

This is for the standard grid control not the datagrid control.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you have code to get your single cell selection working, so I assume that you have code that will determine whether there is a `Grid` at the `MousePosition` when the user clicks the mouse button.

All you need to do to enable the multi select functionality is to also monitor the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event as well. If you detect that the mouse down point was over `Grid` cell (0, 1) and the mouse up point was over `Grid` cell (3, 1), then you can determine that the user has clicked and dragged across cells 1 - 4 in row 1 of the `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your post sheridan - it helped me through the thought process of what I needed:

capture the events for:

1. mouse left button down
2. mouse move
3. mouse left button up

all sorted
:)